# List of existing canonical questions AND the place to propose that a question be canonized

Tags: discusión, faq, preguntas-canónicas

A lo largo del tiempo se ha ido creando, eligiendo o identificando ciertas preguntas/respuestas como [canónicas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) para determinados casos.

Estas son las respuestas en las que la comunidad ha respondido exhaustivamente a un tema determinado. Ulteriores casos son muy específicos, algo diferentes o no tan importantes. Por ello, se ha acabado escribiendo una respuesta que se designa como canónica en el tema.

Por ello, en la respuesta aceptada a esta pregunta listaremos este tipo de preguntas/respuestas.

Por favor:

- Publica una respuesta para nominar una pregunta para su inclusión en la lista. **Cuando una de las propuestas llegue a un balance positivo de al menos +2, se incluirá en la lista oficial.**
- Elimina el contenido que ya esté en la lista oficial (es decir, la respuesta aceptada). Así tendremos esta publicación actualizada. También puedes indicarlo a los moderadores con un *flag* para que ellos la eliminen.

---

Over time we have created, selected, or identified certain question/answer pairs as [canonical](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) for certain topics.

These are answers in which the community has given a thorough, complete answer on a particular topic.

A list of these questions appears in the accepted answer below.

Please:

- Post an Answer to nominate a question for inclusion here. **Once the nomination gets a net score of +2, it will be added to the list.**
- Delete content that has been merged into the official list. In this way the post can be kept tidy and up to date.

Comment: Basado en esta publicación de [sf]: [What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/200076),

Comment: ¿Es requerido que las preguntas son escribido en tanto inglés y español?

Comment: @iBug no. En general, las ponemos en ambos idiomas una vez las marcamos como canónicas.

Comment: Gracias. Se ve como una solución mejor.

Comment: @fedorqui - Iba a editar el título para mostrar que esta página sirve para reunir todas las preguntas canónicas que ya tenemos, y además para proponer nuevas, pero luego pensé que esta estructura es quizás no del todo ideal.  Voy a hacer un nuevo post.

Comment: @fedorqui - bien, si tú prefieres que esta página combine las dos cosas, está bien.  Propuse un edit al título, a ver qué opinas.

Comment: @aparente001 creo que la parte esencial de la pregunta es indicar cuáles son, es lo que nos llevaría el 99% de visitas. La parte de añadir es menor y mucho menos común. Dicho lo cual, y para no entrar en constantes revisiones, miremos cómo funciona así y si un 3.º quiere buscar otra alternativa, pues adelante. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui - No me molesta si quieres editarlo un poco más.  Lo que pasó es que cuando estaba buscando esta página, vi el título y quedé con la duda, si era la página correcta.  Opté por incluir la versión en inglés nomás para que el título no quedara demasiado largo, y me pareció que es importante que los estudiantes del español puedan encontrar la página, o sea que creo que el inglés será lo más importante en el título en este caso.

Comment: Ahora estoy dudando si debo levantar un flag en mi nueva respuesta para llamar la atención del equipo moderador.

Comment: canonical and canonize really, really grate on my ears. I know SE uses canonical like this: Canonical questions are a broad question/answer pair that is intended to be a duplicate target for commonly asked questions, or address a commonly found problem (for Meta Stack Overflow).  Fine, but they don't use canonize. Thank goodness.  I suggest: that **a question be viewed as canonical**.

Comment: @Lambie see the wiki status? It is ready to get your improvements

Comment: Nota: inicialmente intentamos que las preguntas canónicas llevaran versión en castellano e inglés. Sin embargo, hace poco se quitó de muchas ([ejemplo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/18440/10)). Sería bueno un. debate al respecto, para no hacer perder trabajo a unos y otros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Estas son las preguntas que se han identificado como canónicas a lo largo del tiempo

These are the questions we have identified as Canonical:

- [When is it written with and without accent: porqué/porque/por qué? / ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "porque", "porqué", "por que" y "por qué"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14/)
- [Revisions of Spanish orthography / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/)
- [Etymologically, why do "ser" and "estar" exist?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18440/)
- [What are the differences between "ser" and "estar"? When to use each? // ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre "ser" y "estar"? ¿Cuándo se usa cada uno?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/)  - falta traducción al castellano
- [What is the semantic difference between present perfect and pluperfect?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/)
- [When should you use the preterite or the imperfect to express past time?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/417/)
- [All about datives, or: What's that funny "le" or "me" doing in there?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/)
- [How many verbal forms are there in Spanish? // ¿Cuántas formas verbales hay en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5180/12637)
- [Why is "agua" masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? "El agua" / "Las aguas"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/44/12637)
- [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/12637)
- [Redundant indirect object pronoun: is "le" redundant in "preguntémosle al estúpido / a él"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32243/12637)
- [Are there three past continuous tenses in Spanish? When can I use Pretérito imperfecto / imperfecto progresivo / indefinido progresivo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29155/12637)
- [What are the accent placement rules in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/661/12637)

Comment: I think the one about "Resources for..." should be broken down to individual questions with its answer. Someone with a doubt will likely use the search engine using keywords from their question. E.g., I [made a question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17405/12991) whose answer was buried in that one but how could have I known.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv mmmm maybe. I suggest you to post it as a feature-request here in Meta and see what others think about it. Thanks!

Comment: I never did it one of these before @fedorqui. Just copying the commentary adding [tag:feature-request] tag, I suppose?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv yes, only that in Meta: `[meta-tag:feature-request]` -> [meta-tag:feature-request]

Comment: There are grammar mistakes in this in English: When is it written with and without accent: porqué/porque/por qué? It should be changed to: When do porque and por que take an accent (por qué and porqué)? For example.

Comment: @Lambie feel free to edit the posts that are linked, this is a community contribution

Answer (score 2):

Sugiero:

- [Cómo usar el leísmo en el ejemplo “Será mejor que le ayudes [a ella]”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17606/1674) - leísmo/laísmo/loísmo, iria bien cambiar el título a uno más genérico.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero:

- [How to pronounce the consonants "y" and "ll"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-to-pronounce-the-consonants-y-and-ll)

Creo que es común para los estudiantes principiantes de un idioma centrarse en la fonética y así que es una duda común entre ellos . Más que todo en Argentina y Uruguay, el "ll" tiene una pronunciación muy distinta que puede confundir cualquier estudiante de español.

Answer (score 0):

I think [¿Cómo se puede hacer formalmente una petición a la RAE para actualizar una entrada del diccionario?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28299/12991) would be a good one.

Note: ATOW the form is down "hasta el próximo lunes". It might be a transient issue or just like the sign "Hoy no se fía, mañana sí".

---

Creo que [¿Cómo se puede hacer formalmente una petición a la RAE para actualizar una entrada del diccionario?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28299/12991) sería una buena candidata.

Nota: A día de hoy, el formularío está deshabilitado "hasta el próximo lunes". Podría ser un problema pasajero o como lo del cartel de "Hoy no se fía, mañana sí".

Answer (score 0):

Propongo ['Lo bastante/suficientemente + adjetivo + como para' - Is it possible to drop 'lo' and 'como para'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/lo-bastante-suficientemente-adjetivo-como-para-is-it-possible-to-drop-l) Creo que sería muy útil para los principiantes.

Comment: Este post tiene un error.  Luego busco el enlace correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero:

- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre tú, usted y vos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/7/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-t%c3%ba-usted-y-vos)

La diferencia entre "tú" y "usted" es una cuestión común de hablantes nativos de lenguas que tienen un solo pronombre personal para 2ª persona singular y plural , como el inglés.

El pronombre personal "vos" es especialmente relevante en América Latina. Nunca me lo enseñaron en mis clases de español y me confundió cuando viajé a Argentina (donde "vos" es muy común en el lenguaje informal) por primera vez.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero:

[Significance of adjective placement](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/328/significance-of-adjective-placement)

Decidir si un adjetivo cualitativo viene antes o después de un sustantivo es una duda común de hablantes nativos de inglés, donde el adjetivo cualitativo siempre viene antes que el sustantivo.

Answer (score -1):

Dejaré esto por aquí:

- [Is there a Spanish equivalent to "-ish"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/is-there-a-spanish-equivalent-to-ish)

Para nominarla como respuesta pregunta canónica, ademas de la muy excelente y votada respuesta que recibió.

Comment: It's a fun Q&A, nicely handled.  But I think canonical questions should be mainly for basic grammar.  I think canonical questions are for questions that get asked over and over again, in various forms.  "Ish" isn't going to get asked again and again.

Answer (score -2):

Sugiero esta pregunta también :

- [Palabra más polivalente del español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17100/14033)

Gracias

Comment: Voto en contra. Creo que es una pregunta más del ámbito de curiosidades que de temas que requieran de respuestas sesudas y definitivas.

Comment: Mi Contraargumento es que una de las características definitivas del castellano en contraste con otros idiomas es la riqueza y diversidad de su vocabulario tanto en variedad (sinónimos o voces distintas para un mismo concepto) como en profundidad (asepciones, conceptos distintos para una misma voz). Esta pregunta muestra claramente una de esas dimensiones.