# ¿Qué hacemos con la etiqueta "pretéritos"? Subdividamos según el tipo

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, reetiquetado

Acabo de aprender que *Pretérito perfecto simple* de toda la vida también puede llamarse *Pretérito* a secas (dadle a [conjugar en la palabra *ser*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm)).

Trasladado a este sitio, esto quiere decir que la etiqueta [pretérito](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pret%c3%a9rito) debería usarse para referirnos a esta forma del indicativo.

Sin embargo, de las formas simples estas son las que contienen *pretérito* en su nombre, lo que puede llevar a confusión:

Indicativo:

- Pretérito imperfecto / Copretérito
- Condicional simple / Pospretérito
- Pretérito perfecto simple / Pretérito

Subjuntivo:

- Pretérito imperfecto / Copretérito

Y de hecho esto ocurre: observo que se usa de una forma más genérica para englobar a todos los pretéritos. Por ejemplo en [¿Cómo aplicamos el pretérito pluscuamperfecto continuo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17439/1674) se usa para hablar del pluscuamperfecto.

Por tanto, **propongo**:

- Resevar [pretérito](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pret%c3%a9rito) para las más genéricas
- Crear las siguientes más específicas:

  - [pretérito-imperfecto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pret%c3%a9rito-imperfecto) (ya existía como *imperfecto* y la acabo de renombrar)
  - [condicional-simple](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/condicional-simple)
  - [pretérito-perfecto-simple](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pret%c3%a9rito-perfecto-simple) (también existe)
  - [pretérito-imperfecto-subjuntivo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pret%c3%a9rito-imperfecto-subjuntivo)

De esta forma podremos poner orden a preguntas del tipo [Pretérito indefinido vs pretérito imperfecto: ¿“estaba” or “estuve un poco enfermo el fin de semana pasado”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18923/1674), conseguir jerarquizarlas y [promover alguna canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) si se da el caso.

De lo contrario, tendremos multitud de preguntas parecidas con etiquetas raras y estaremos todo el tiempo respondiendo lo mismo.

Recordemos: si etiquetamos bien, podremos encontrar mejor.

Comment: My immediate reaction was that if they know which of your proposed more specific tags to use they probably already know the answer to their question. Certainly as a native English speaker I am not very familiar with the Spanish grammatical names even for things which I think I understand. I know you are proposing to leave the generic tag for people like me.

Comment: El término «pretérito», a secas, para referir a las conjugaciones como *fui* y no *era*, vienen de la terminología de Andrés Bello.  En este sistema, se dice «copretérito» y no «pretérito imperfecto» para *era*, y «pospretérito» y no «condicional» para *sería*

Comment: @guifa ajá, no sabía el origen de esta terminología. Para mí es muy extraña, en la educación en España nunca la oí. No sé qué tan común es, pero mi sugerencia es la de ceñirnos a la terminología ¿clásica? y usar las etiquetas "pretérito-imperfecto", "condicional", etc.