# ¿Responder de acuerdo al uso coloquial o de acuerdo a las reglas del idioma?

Tags: discusión

Dado que el lenguaje es dinámico y está en constante cambio, es habitual que primero se genere una nueva forma de expresión, y sólo después se acepte como norma dentro del lenguaje.

Cuando una persona hace una pregunta respecto de cómo se dice, escribe o pronuncia algo, surge la duda de si aquella pregunta debe responderse de acuerdo a las reglas vigentes o a lo que coloquialmente se usa en el lenguaje diario.

Por ejemplo, los casos donde empiezan a usarse formas neutras en género o se agregan formas femeninas de palabras que solo tienen una versión masculina. También hay casos recientes de cambios que realiza RAE y que representan un genocidio a respuestas anteriormente correctas que tenía este sitio, en cuyo caso habría que indicar que una respuesta era correcta hasta cierta fecha.

También hay diferencias regionales respecto de pronunciaciones u ortografía, que chocan con lo que uno esperaría observar como la forma correcta del lenguaje.

Entonces. ¿Cuál debería ser la norma para responder preguntas que tienen distintas respuestas dependiendo de lo que dictan las normas o el uso real del lenguaje?

Comment: Ejemplos, por favor.  Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

> *Lo que sigue es mi opinión. No soy moderador del sitio y por tanto lo dicho abajo no debe interpretarse como la posición oficial sobre lo que hacer en los casos que planteas.*

---

Bueno, el primer escenario es fácil: **si esa persona especifica que está buscando un tipo u otro de respuesta**, es decir, solo respuestas sobre el uso coloquial, o por el contrario solo respuestas basadas en la norma oficial, entonces **la respuesta debe ser en esos términos**, principalmente.

**Si la pregunta es más general**, entonces **lo mejor es dar ambas opciones en la respuesta**: valgan como modestos ejemplos [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26309/13628) y [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26311/13628) respuestas mías* donde ofrezco tanto los términos recogidos en el DLE para lo que se pregunta, como otros que también se usan coloquialmente para lo mismo aunque su definición en el diccionario no sea la misma o no aparezcan siquiera.

Por supuesto, respuestas que se centren solo en acepciones y normas oficiales o solo en usos coloquiales también son aceptables, faltaría más.
No obstante, para aquellas que ofrecen como respuesta **una expresión popular** pero no recogida oficialmente, **es deseable que esté respaldada con fuentes y ejemplos**, sean de prensa, de foros, de vídeos... Esto es para evitar [situaciones parecidas a esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21965/13628), en las que un usuario pueda responder con una expresión que lleva oyendo toda su vida y que piensa que es un dicho común y extendido, cuando en realidad es algo exclusivo de su círculo familiar.

Sobre las **respuestas que quedan obsoletas** por cambios recientes, lo adecuado es: **acudir a las mismas y editarlas**, bien para corregirlas (si hacerlo no desvirtúa la respuesta), bien para indicar que la respuesta está desfasada; **o proponer una nueva respuesta** con información actualizada. Un debate relacionado con esto se planteó en [What to do with older, highly voted, but wrong answers?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2912)

Sobre preguntas en las que influyen las diferencias regionales, hay cientos de respuestas en el sitio que las abordan de manera satisfactoria. En ocasiones se deja que cada usuario responda con las particularidades de su región, en otros casos (los más simples, normalmente) se juntan todas las respuestas en una única respuesta común, tal como se propuso en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2483)

Aquí hago un inciso: mencionas «diferencias regionales respecto de [...] ortografía».
**No estoy de acuerdo en que tal cosa exista**.
La ortografía del español es la que es y está así establecida, no solo por la RAE, sino por las [23 academias que conforman la ASALE](http://www.asale.org/academias), incluyendo las 20 americanas, la española, la filipina y la ecuatoguineana. Es cierto que no se pronuncia igual ZAMBULLIDA en todas las regiones: la inmensa mayoría pronuncia `/sambuyida/`, mientras que otras más minoritarias (como España) pronuncian `/zambullida/`, `/sambushida/` o `/sampuyia/`. Pero la palabra es la misma: ZAMBULLIDA, y así se debe escribir si queremos seguir entendiéndonos mediante el español como lengua común. Por eso **la ortografía debe ser, y es, la misma para todos**. Las diferencias de pronunciación no son más que eso: diferencias de pronunciación. Y escribir **sambullida*, **sanbullida*, **zambuyida* no son diferencias regionales: son faltas de ortografía.

Mención aparte merecen las preguntas que versan específicamente sobre usos no acordes a la ortografía, como por ejemplo [Is the use of @ instead of 'a' or 'o' in order to refer to both masculine and femenine accepted?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/342) o [Use of "x" instead of "ch" in internetslang](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16203), donde es comprensible que las respuestas expliquen el significado y uso de ciertas formas ortográficamente incorrectas, siempre dejando claro que no son correctas (de momento :D).

**Resumiendo**: el español es muy amplio: se habla en Asia, en África, en Europa y en toda América. Esto hace que existan diferencias fonéticas, semánticas... pero, por suerte, hablamos uno de los pocos idiomas que se ha molestado en establecer unas normas más o menos básicas para que el español siga siendo español en todas partes. Y además no son unas normas escritas en piedra, sino que evolucionan junto con el idioma, porque el español es una lengua viva.
Nuestra tarea como espacio en el que resolver dudas sobre el español, es tener en cuenta los usos más actuales, claro, pero procurando siempre explicarlos bajo la luz de la norma recogida y dejando claro en qué sentidos se acercan o se alejan de la misma, cómo de aceptados son, etc.

<sub><sub>* Disculpas por el autobombo: aunque casi todos los usuarios "top" siguen el mismo criterio en sus respuestas, las mías son las que mejor recuerdo si se basaban en fuentes oficiales o en un uso coloquial, sin necesidad de ponerme a buscar.</sub></sub>