# Can the moderator remove the misleading green checkmark?

Tags: discusión, soporte, preguntas-canónicas

Can the moderator remove the misleading green checkmark at [Redundant indirect object pronoun "preguntémosle al estupido / a él"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32243/9385)?

If not, then I think we need to ask a new question and ask @Charo to transfer her answer.

Comment: [Related Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111529/350184). Basically, if an answer is blatantly wrong it should be voted to be deleted, and with deletion comes the removing of the green mark. Problem is, does the accepted answer deserve to be deleted? If not, then it is just the OP decision to keep the green mark where it is now, or move it somewhere else.

Comment: Also, consider commenting this with the author of the accepted answer, or even improving it (it is CW now). Then, a good approach is to contact the OP. Finally, see a similar question: [What to do with older, highly voted, but wrong answers?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2912/1674)

Comment: According to my understanding of the voting process, it should be VOTES and not the green checkmark (accepted answer) what validates a contribution. I think that the site even gives badges if your answer has 2X the votes of the accepted answer. [We don't vote much](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5481) and run into these kind of issues, but it should be the whole community and not just one person (even if they are the OP of the question) who validates the content. The OP merely says "that best answer for my question", and the community says "that's the BEST answer"

Comment: I don't know if the question is actually a request or or an actual question about functionality. In any case, I would treat it like the latter and provide an answer that is basically Ferdoqui's comment "Nobody apart from the OP can accept or unaccept an answer" + link to doc. Then, we could use this question as a cannonical question/answer for all of such requests. As Fedorqui explains, we can suggest to people what to consider, but we cannot tell users what to accept/unaccept for their questions (or what to upvote/downvote, flag, etc.) or tamper with their contributions in that way.

Comment: The accepted answer is now a community wiki and it is in fact the community which has decided to promote it to a canonical answer voting in this [Meta post](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3281/). So, even what you are asking as an alternative option, would be anti-democratic. I insist on this: please feel free to take whatever you want from my answer to add it to the community wiki one.