# What topics do we need canonical answers for?

Tags: discusión, preguntas-canónicas

We have some canonical Q-As (listed in [¿Qué preguntas canónicas tenemos? What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)), but we need more, so that we can point learners to some reliable information every time certain often-asked questions come up, such as ***subjunctive***.  Let's collect in one place a list of the top priority topics that we really ought to have a canonical answer for.  I propose that we do it in a community wiki answer here.

(To come up with a canonical q-a, sometimes it's helpful to start with an existing Q-A and perhaps edit it a bit, sometimes it's better to start from scratch.)

*This question came up when I read a recent [question about the subjunctive](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30289/9385) from someone who knows stackexchange inside and out, but it looked as though they had apparently not read the basics about the subjunctive that have already been covered here.  Then I realized that it is not easy to find the basics that have already been covered about the subjunctive here!*

Comment: By the way --not sure if I should post a separate question about this-- we REALLY need a link to the list of canonical questions in a permanent box on the main site.

Comment: Great idea! This can work well as a way to _request_ canonicals, while [¿Qué preguntas canónicas tenemos? What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) works to _list_ them.

Comment: @walen - I just double-checked that participant's profile -- I was confusing them with someone else I know from ELU, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**Subjunctive**: an introduction

Maybe later someone would want to do something more complete, but I would like to see us get started with something introductory.  I think Pablo or somebody like that already did this but I'm having trouble finding it.

What people want to know is, When should I use the subjunctive?  There should be some examples from the basic tenses.

Comment: He añadido un par de entradas a la lista. El hacer la respuesta community wiki me parece buena idea, pero también va a hacer más dificil validar las aportaciones. Por ejemplo, si alguien no está de acuerdo conmigo que "ser vs estar" es una de las posibilidades hay que discutirlo vía comment. En respuestas separadas se puede votar cada entrada individual, lo que da más trabajo, pero valida cada entrada.

Comment: @Diego buena observación. Podríamos empezar así y si la cosa se sale de madre ya lo repensamos, ¿qué te parece? Por otra parte, de _ser vs estar_ ya tenemos canónica. Véase la [lista completa de canónicas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2534/1674).

Comment: I think @Diego is right, we should make separate posts, as in the page for tag housekeeping requests.  Another advantage to Diego's proposal is that we can see what our priorities are.  I've gotten that started now, but I didn't add *ser, estar* because I thought that was covered.  If someone feels there's a gap, please write an answer with a broad description of what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

The "personal a" is an important topic for Spanish learners:

The same structure that works fine for inanimate objects, companies, etc., requires the preposition "a" if we put a person in place of the object or company. It comes naturally to Spanish speakers -- but it can trip up Spanish learners.

Simple example: Veo el coche. Veo **a** Laura.  Veo una mesa.  Veo a una niña.

There are lots of finer points that learners ask about.

Comment: @fedorqui - if we could get a tag set up for this topic, it would be easier for me to cite a bunch of questions that ask about the finer points.

Comment: Indeed! Which tags are we using now for these questions? I cannot find any example of such questions. I see [tag:personal-a] is now a synonym to [tag: preposiciones] (I created it) and probably something more self explanatory may work better

Comment: @fedorqui - Gracias pero creo que no debe ser sinónimo de [tag:preposiciones] sino subconjunto.  // Hace poco creo que propuse una etiqueta para "personal *a*" y Charlie no estaba muy de acuerdo.  Ah, ya encontré: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3277/9385

Answer (score 1):

**Ustedeo frente a tuteo**: cuándo usar cada uno y cuál es la conjugación apropiada.

There will need to be a list of countries or regions for this, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Negation.  Learners ask about double negatives again and again.  We need a small, canonical post that covers things like *no* combined with *nunca*, etc.

Comment: @walen - Thanks.  We need synonyms to go with it -- maybe *negation, negative, double-negative*.

Answer (score 1):

Several times, people have asked questions about the **redundant indirect object pronoun**, and have either found the canonical question about "that funny *le*" or have been directed there.  It would be good to have a short-ish q-a page about the redundancy, in one place, that we can point to for duplicate questions.

Also, maybe it would be good to have a tag for this.