# ¿Cómo de estrictos debemos ser al cerrar preguntas como duplicados?

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre, votos-de-cierre

La motivación de esta pregunta viene de esta otra pregunta: [No se me preocupe - meaning of “me”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32333/24236).

Es [una](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32172/24236) [de](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32190/24236) [muchas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32169/24236) preguntas que han aparecido recientemente sobre el dativo ético. Las preguntas incluyen distintos ejemplos de dativo ético, y preguntan por el significado del pronombre de dativo.

En el caso de [No se me preocupe - meaning of “me”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32333/24236), mi primera reacción fue pensar que el significado de "me" es exactamente el mismo que el de "les" en [Se les puso nerviosa - meaning of “les”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32172/24236), y que no tiene sentido escribir otra vez la misma respuesta. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro si en estos casos debo votar para cerrar o no.

#### Argumentos a favor de cerrar

- La frase es un ejemplo de la misma figura de lenguaje que en la otra pregunta, y por tanto la respuesta sería la misma que en la otra pregunta.
- Quizá no nos interesa que nuestra lista de preguntas activas/recientas se componga mayoritariamente de distintos ejemplos de dativo ético

#### Argumentos en contra de cerrar

- La frase es distinta a la de la otra pregunta. Para el que pregunta (y para otros hablantes no nativos que vengan al sitio más tarde) puede no ser obvio que las dos frases son un ejemplo de lo mismo. La nueva respuesta añadiría la nueva información de que esta nueva frase también incluye un dativo ético.
- No es el caso que el usuario que pregunta no haya buscado antes para ver si hay duplicados. Él realmente no tiene claro qué significa ese pronombre, y otras preguntas del sitio no le ayudan.
- Parece que tenemos poco tráfico. Si cerramos demasiadas preguntas, será aún peor.

Soy un usuario relativamente nuevo que ha recibido un "martillo" (perdónese el anglicismo) relativamente grande (votar para cerrar), así que quiero saber cuál es la política para estos casos.

#### ¿Debemos cerrar las preguntas que pregunten sobre nuevos ejemplos de algo ya aclarado en otra pregunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el caso que comentas se está sugiriendo cerrar como duplicada una pregunta de un autor por otra de ese mismo autor. Ese es un matiz importante a tener en cuenta. En base a ello, mis opiniones:

Si la pregunta es muy parecida, lo suyo sería animar al autor a que aclare sus dudas en la primera pregunta, vía comentarios. Si la duda que le surge es parecida a lo que planteó inicialmente, preguntar de nuevo suena un poco excesivo. De hecho, [se lo comenté hace un tiempo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32190/what-is-the-meaning-of-le-in-el-coche-no-anda-porque-se-le-descarg%C3%B3-la-bate#comment57695_32190) y a todos nos corresponde huir de respuestas simples a cosas muy concretas e intentar crear contenido útil que parta de lo concreto para crear casuística más general.

La gracia de las preguntas duplicadas es que el contenido "bueno" se concentre en un sitio, en lugar de tener pedacitos de información repartida en muchas preguntas similares. Por ello, lo suyo es que si vemos que una pregunta está generando muchas preguntas similares o está concentrando muchos duplicados, analicemos si la podemos generalizar un poco (intentando respetar la idea inicial -o no-) o bien directamente generar una pregunta canónica desde cero, que no sea un tocho larguísimo pero que sí recopile las dudas más comunes.

Dado que muchos venimos del mundo de la programación, pensemos en un símil fácil: imaginemos que en Stack Overflow alguien un día pregunta sobre cómo crear una clase con un atributo piña. Al día siguiente, otro pregunta sobre lo mismo pero con uva, y se la marcan como duplicado de la de piña. Ante la queja del de la uva, lo suyo sería generalizar la pregunta original y adaptarlo al caso genérico de "fruta" o similar.

Sugerencias sobre el tema:

- [¿Qué respuestas canónicas tenemos? What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)
- [What topics do we need canonical answers for?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3079/1674)

Comment: Ya tenemos una [pregunta canónica al respecto de los dativos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26171/12637).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando yo recién empecé a participar en este sitio, me daba por votar a cerrar muchas preguntas por falta de esfuerzo, y mis valientes colegas me señalaron que hay que ser un poco flexibles en este sitio, en comparación con algunos sitios más rigurosos, como por ejemplo English Language & Usage.

Pero creo que podemos hacer una distinción entre los que apenas están tomando sus primeros pasos con el idioma y con el sitio, y los que ya tienen tiempecito con los dos, y exigir a los últimos que muestren esfuerzo.

Por lo tanto, estoy de acuerdo con la idea de cerrar cuando ya se trató el tema en otra pregunta, o cerrar por falta de esfuerzo, si no es un principiante total.