# How to categorize questions about the personal "a"

Tags: discusión, soporte, etiquetas

I was looking to see if we have a tag about the "personal *a*" and it did show up in the list of tags as [personal-a](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-a).  However, there were no questions associated with it.  I tried adding it anyway, and failed.  I tried to recreate it and failed at that too.  What should I do?  I do think it would be a helpful tag.  It's something people ask about, and I think it would be a good topic for a canonical Q-A.

Comment: It is a synonym of [tag:preposiciones]: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: @fedorqui - Expliqué en otra parte (disculpa, ahorita no recuerdo dónde) que "personal *a*" es un *subconjunto* de *preposiciones*, no un sinónimo.  Es un tema importante para los estudiantes del español.  El sistema de etiquetear las preguntas existe precisamente para ayudar a los usuarios a encontrar otras preguntas sobre el mismo tema.

Comment: Sí, leí que lo comentaste. Ya sé de oa utilidad de las etiquetas :) comenté que era sinónimo para explicar por qué no tiene preguntas asociadas.

Comment: Ah, ya veo, gracias. ¿Y? ¿Tienes alguna idea creadora, cómo podríamos etiquetear las preguntas de este subtema?  ¿Podríamos empezar con deshacer la relación de sinonimidad?

Comment: Me parece bien lo que propuso Charlie de etiquetarlas con [tag:complemento-directo] y [tag:preposiciones].

Comment: @fedorqui - Pero este tema es más específico.  Es para complementos directos que son *personas*.

Comment: No sé cuál es el término usado para ello, habría que investigar en la literatura. ¿complemento-directo-personal?

Comment: @fedorqui - Pablodf sabrá.  Quizás ukemi o wimi.

Comment: Pensando de nuevo sobre esto, me parece bien quitar el sinónimo existente

Comment: @fedorqui - Gracias por reconsiderar.  Por lo pronto, ¿ves bien que vaya poniendo "a-personal" poco a poco a las preguntas correspondientes?

Comment: Por mí sí, pero sería bueno comentarlo con otras personas para ver si es útil. ¿Qué dijeron pablo, ukemi o wimi?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the "personal-a" tag redirects to the [preposiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposiciones) tag. We're trying to have our tags written in Spanish, with English tags that redirect to the Spanish ones, similar to what other language-related sites do.

The personal *a* affects direct objects, so I suppose such questions should be tagged both as [complemento-directo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complemento-directo) and [preposiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposiciones), or any other relevant tag. The problem I see is that the personal *a* does not have a specific name in Spanish. Reading the Spanish grammar by the RAE I read "complemento directo introducido por la preposición *a*", which is quite a long name for a tag.

Right now there are only two question tagged with those two tags, and it seems that none of them asks about the personal *a*. Maybe we should retag the questions that do with those two tags. Please, if anybody has another opinion do not hesitate to share it with us in another answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think the lack of a name for this concept in Spanish should by itself hold us back.  The think is, for native Spanish speakers, this concept comes naturally.  But it's something that Spanish learners have to make some effort to get the hang of.  I see this topic as a subset of the general topic *preposiciones*.

Comment: *thing, not think.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Q-A about the personal *a* that is quite good (in fact, I'm thinking about proposing it as a canonical Q-A): [¿Debo usar la 'a personal' con un personaje antropomorfo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22713/9385)

In his answer there, Pablo uses the term *a personal* (writing in Spanish).  From this I conclude that that's what this topic is called in Spanish.

Therefore, I have created a tag [a-personal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-personal) as an experiment.  I propose that this be synonymized with "personal-a", and then this will be *problem solved*!

(There is another [Q](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29030/9385) that uses the term --in English-- "personal object," which also looks quite good.  I suggest that that be synonymized with "a-personal" as well.)

Comment: La gramática de la RAE los denomina "complementos directos de persona", especificando que van siempre introducidos por la preposición _a_. No se usan en dicha obra las expresiones "a personal" ni "complemento directo personal".

Comment: @Charlie - entonces, podríamos darle otro sinónimo (*complementos directos de persona*).  Pero los maestros de español, y los libros de texto para los extranjeros, sí enseñan este tema.

Comment: Parece que el tema de los CD de persona es más importante para los que aprenden español de lo que yo pensaba. Si consideráis que una etiqueta específica es apropiada no tengo problema en crearla. Aunque una etiqueta llamada "complemento-directo-de-persona" se me hace un poco larga, y tampoco sé si es el término más usado o el más correcto. En todo caso, se puede proponer uno como el "oficial" y crear los sinónimos necesarios para que la gente encuentre la etiqueta fácilmente.

Comment: @Charlie i can remember when I first learned Spanish that I flatly refused to believe that it was necessary to put a before personal direct objects since it seemed totally  unnecessary. Do we have a question about its origins I wonder?

Comment: @mdewey yes, we do: [_What is the history of the "personal a"?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3719/12637). I did not know about the existence of that question, I have just upvoted it (and the useful answers).

Comment: @Charlie I have to say I did not find them that helpful since although it is true that it avoids ambiguity that still leaves open why Spanish developed that use of the Latin ad whereas French, Italian and Portuguese do not seem to need it. No idea about Catalan, Gallego and so on (nor Romanian).