# Canonical question for "required duplicate indirect object" (aka "redundant indirect object pronoun")

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, preguntas-canónicas

In the comments to [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32573/24236), *several* (as in "strictly more than one") users have suggested to add a canonical question about the "required duplicate indirect object", i. e., the need to have both **a noun** and *a pronoun* referring to the same indirect object in sentences such as

- **A los españoles** *les* llevó años reconquistar la Península Ibérica

The [relevant suggestion](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3216/24236) in [What topics do we need canonical answers for?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3079/24236) has *several* upvotes, so I write this question to discuss which question should we canonize for this purpose. I see several options:

1. Canonize [What is the role of the “le” in the sentence “Miguel le dio a su novia un anillo.”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104/24236): This is the only question on the topic that is not marked as duplicate.
2. Canonize [Redundant indirect object pronoun “preguntémosle al estupido / a él”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32251/24236): as I said in the mentioned comment thread, I prefer this one because I think my answer there is more complete because it says when it is optional and when it is required.
3. Write a new question and answer.

I have written community-wiki answers for options 1. and 2. If you agree with one of these options, please upvote the relevant answer. If you agree with option 3., please write an answer saying what you think should be included in the new answer (just a summary, I do not think a full, final version is needed yet).

We can then implement the most upvoted option if it reaches a certain threshold of votes (maybe 3?).

Comment: I like the way you set it up.  I'm going to wait to see what Pablo thinks because he's been our main canonical answer writer so far.  (I've made some "assists.")

Comment: I vote for Option 2. It covers a range of possibilities, it is sourced and would only need minor edits.

Comment: I cannot vote for any option because I am not allowed to vote for my own answers, even if they are community wiki. So I am forced to be impartial here.

Comment: Well, you can tell us which you prefer, even if you can't vote.

Comment: @aparente001 I already did that in the question: I prefer option 2

Comment: After reflecting about it, I've also voted for option 2 because I think it would be a way of solving the problem mentioned by @wimi in this [answer](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3304).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 2. Canonize [Redundant indirect object pronoun “preguntémosle al estupido / a él”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32251/24236)

Vote for this answer if you agree with this option.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this question is currently marked as a duplicate of the question in option 1. If this ends up being the most upvoted option I would suggest to invert that and mark option 1 as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Charlie: I wasn't aware of this question until now (sorry!): I now realise that what you are saying in your comment has to do with I'm explaining in this [question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3303/).

Comment: @Charo no need to be sorry. I should have handled this subject long ago. This has been the most upvoted answer and it's been a month since it was posted, so maybe we should mark it as accepted and proceed with the canonization, hence solving the problem you addressed.

Comment: @Charlie 4 plus my vote is 5, I guess that is enough. I have voted to reopen the closed question, this is the only thing I can do to start implementing this...

Comment: @Charo si se implementa esta opción, haré mi respuesta *community wiki* y entonces podrás añadirle lo que quieras. Me puedes escribir un comentario en la respuesta si se me olvida.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1:  Canonize [What is the role of the “le” in the sentence “Miguel le dio a su novia un anillo.”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104/24236)

Vote for this answer if you agree with this option