# ¿Tiene sentido indicar que una pregunta es un duplicado de una publicación cerrada?

Tags: discusión, preguntas-cerradas, duplicados-exactos

En mi opinión, cuando se cierra una pregunta como duplicada, no es únicamente para indicar "la respuesta a tu pregunta la puedes encontrar aquí". Es también para decir "esta pregunta ya se ha hecho antes y aquí podrás encontrar respuestas ya dadas o que se añadirán en el futuro".

Por eso, creo que no tiene demasiado sentido que una pregunta se indique como duplicada de otra que está cerrada, como pasa ahora mismo en [este caso](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32923): aunque la pregunta cerrada tenga respuestas, ningún usuario puede añadir nuevas respuestas y vendría a ser como decir "aquí está todo ya escrito sobre este asunto y nadie puede añadir nada de nada".

No me refiero al momento de votar por cerrar una pregunta como duplicado, sino a cómo se deja finalmente la pregunta una vez cerrada (y eso puede requerir la revisión por parte de un moderador).

Yo pienso que se debería o bien marcar la pregunta como un duplicado de otra que no estuviera cerrada (en el ejemplo citado podría ser [esta otra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104)), o bien poner una lista de preguntas debajo de "This question already has answers here:" en la que al menos una no esté cerrada.

Otra posibilidad sería cambiar la pregunta que se deja abierta y la que se cierra como duplicado si se considera conveniente por alguna razón, pero considero importante que las preguntas cerradas tengan un enlace a al menos una pregunta abierta (puede haber, además, enlaces a preguntas cerradas).

Por último, si se trata de duplicados realmente exactos con respuestas, también en algún caso se puede considerar la opción del "merge", aunque esto puede dar lugar a situaciones "curiosas" como la que se explica en [esta pregunta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1354).

¿Qué opináis al respecto?

**Actualización:**

El ejemplo concreto que había puesto ya se ha resuelto reabriendo la pregunta que se había indicado como duplicado de la publicación recientemente cerrada, pero lo que planteo aquí pretende ser general y no referirse únicamente a ese caso (aunque quizás sea un aspecto menor de la gestión del sitio y no sea necesario darle más vueltas).

Comment: Creo que tienes razón y no se deberían "enlazar" duplicados (cerrar C por ser duplicado de B que a su vez está cerrada como duplicado de A, que sí sigue abierta, y en su lugar cerrar C como duplicado de A). El problema es que hay una cierta complejidad al cerrar preguntas (p.ej. el título se parece más al "duplicado" que al "original", o se marca como duplicado porque se responde en una respuesta a otra pregunta que preguntaba otra cosas distinta). Pero en definitiva tienes razón y deberíamos tomarnos el tiempo necesario para marcar correctamente la pregunta que se duplica la votar par cerrar.

Comment: De todas formas, @Diego, hay la posibilidad de indicar varias preguntas como referencia una vez cerrado el post.

Comment: @Diego: En el momento de votar no pienso que sea problema. Me refiero a como se deja la pregunta una vez cerrada (y eso puede requerir la revisión por parte de un moderador).

Comment: @Charo la razón del cierre "unilateral" es que el OP ha aceptado la sugerencia de duplicado. Si el OP hace esto, la pregunta se cierra automáticamente, y "Community" aparece como último "close-voter".

Comment: Ah, vale, @wimi: ¡gracias por la aclaración! Como he dicho una vez vi que pasó en Italian.SE y me quedé con la duda de entender qué había pasado.

Comment: @Charo esto que comentas ocurre cuando alguien vota para cerrar como duplicado. Entonces si el autor de la pregunta (AP) ve el texto "¿Esto resuelve tu pregunta?" y dice que sí (sale un botón) el usuario Community vota de forma definitiva (binding vote) y la pregunta queda cerrrada. Vaya, que es porque el AP ha estado de acuerdo en que es duplicada ([referencia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/209901)).

Comment: Sí, gracias, @fedorqui'SOstopharming': lo he entendido.

Comment: Sobre tu actualización: mi respuesta pretendía cubrir el caso general, no este concreto.

Comment: Sí, @fedorqui'SOstopharming': me había quedado claro desde el principio. Lo que pasa es que no sé muy bien cómo se puede interpretar el hecho que únicamente yo haya dado un voto a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando propongo un duplicado, o cuando respondo a una pregunta, mi objetivo principal es dar una respuesta **correcta**. Por esta razón, no quiero proponer como duplicada una pregunta [cuya respuesta aceptada y más votada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2105/24236) es incorrecta*, como en este caso. [La nueva respuesta de Charo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32926/24236) es correcta, pero (1) no estaba cuando yo voté para cerrar y (2) está tan abajo que no es fácil que ayude a visitantes del sitio que realmente no sepan la respuesta.

Si seguimos cerrando nuevas preguntas sobre el tema como duplicados de esta pregunta con una respuesta incorrecta, todos los futuros visitantes del sitio que tengan la misma pregunta serán redirigidos a una respuesta falsa. No veo ningún sentido lógico a esto, y por esta razón no quiero votar a esta pregunta como objetivo del duplicado.

Hace un mes escribí [una pregunta en Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3281/24236) para intentar resolver este problema, pero no ha tenido suficiente participación. Los pocos usuarios que participaron, sin embargo, parecen estar de acuerdo en que la pregunta que actualmente está abierta no tenía respuestas merecedoras de ser canónicas (repito: esto era antes de que Charo añadiese su respuesta).

*Por supuesto, es posible que yo sea el único usuario que considera esa respuesta "incorrecta" (aunque, como he dicho, hay ciertas indicaciones de que no). Pero para estos casos, está bien que mi voto sea solo uno, y la comunidad puede fácilmente tomar por mayoría una decisión distinta, que yo por supuesto aceptaré.

Comment: Yo creo que puedes dar por finalizada la encuesta de la otra pregunta: dos personas votaron por una y ninguna por otra, por lo que lo suyo sería implementarlo invirtiendo los duplicados.

Comment: @wimi: Creo que no me explicado del todo bien. He añadido alguna frase a mi post para intentar corregirlo. Mi pregunta no pretendía ser una crítica a tu manera de votar por cerrar la pregunta, que me parece perfectamente correcta. Se refiere a como se dejan al final del proceso de cerrado los posts cerrados (en general).

Comment: También estoy totalmente de acuerdo con el problema que indicas en esta respuesta. Gracias por indicar tu pregunta en Meta: ahora mismo me la miro con detenimiento (*mea culpa*: hasta ahora había participado poquísimo en esta comunidad, con lo cual este tema se me había escapado completamente).

Comment: Respecto a tu "asterisco", yo también estoy totalmente de acuerdo con el hecho de que aquella respuesta es incorrecta: por eso le he dado un voto negativo y he añadido un comentario indicando la razón de mi voto. Pero me doy cuenta que es algo que pasa fácilmente desapercibido, con lo cual no soluciona gran cosa.

Comment: Insisto, @wimi: estoy completamente de acuerdo con las razones que te han llevado a tu propuesta de duplicado en este caso (y puede que yo hubiera hecho exactamente igual que tu). Mi pregunta **no** se refiere a cómo votamos por cerrar y pretende ser más general que el caso específico que hemos mencionado. Además, la "resolución" de este caso específico entiendo que depende de cómo se actúe en consecuencia de lo que pides en la pregunta Meta que indicas. De verdad que me sabe muy mal generar malos entendidos. Disculpa por no haberme explicado bien en mi post.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': Y ahora ya son 3 los votos a la propuesta de pregunta canónica.

Comment: @wimi: Lo que me resulta más sorprendente de todo esto es que la respuesta "incorrecta" siga atrayendo votos positivos (quizá sea yo en buena parte la "culpable": añadiendo mi respuesta creo que he conseguido lo contrario de lo que pretendía). Hoy mismo ha recibido dos votos positivos. ¿Tanta credibilidad se da en esta comunidad a Wikitionary? Me sorprende porque en la comunidad de la que soy moderadora os puedo asegurar que no es así.

Comment: @Charo no te preocupes, no me lo he tomado mal ni nada de eso :). Entiendo lo difícil de la situación:los votos atraen más votos, y no hay forma de eliminar esa respuesta incorrecta de ahí. Estoy completamente de acuerdo con que no tiene sentido cerrar una pregunta como duplicado de otra que ya está cerrada.

Comment: @Charo Pero me cuesta decidirme a iniciar el proceso de invertir los duplicados con solo tres votos a favor, porque eso significaría invalidar una respuesta con 13 votos a favor de una respuesta **mía** con solo 6 votos. No soy juez imparcial en este asunto, y los tres votos en Meta son menos que los 5 votos para cerrar/reabrir necesarios para  implementar la propuesta.

Comment: @Charo pensaré más sobre el tema y en algún momento del fin de semana decidiré si hago algo, hoy no voy a tener tiempo.

Comment: @Charo la propuesta en Meta tiene ahora 4 votos (más el mío, 5), así que creo que se puede implementar. He votado para reabrir la pregunta cerrada.

Comment: Bien, @wimi: me parece una solución correcta. Aunque, de hecho aquí aparente001 ha propuesto una "opción 3" (yo creo que su respuesta la debería haber escrito a tu pregunta en Meta).

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Tiene sentido indicar que una pregunta es un duplicado de una publicación cerrada?

No, no tiene demasiado sentido. La idea de tener preguntas canónicas y preguntas duplicadas es que la canónica absorba el contenido *potente* y así muchas otras preguntas tengan la respuesta en esta. Además, que la pregunta canónica vaya alimentándose constantemente para que el contenido sea lo más útil posible.

Cuando marcamos una pregunta X como duplicada de otra Y que también lo es de una Z, estamos viniendo a decir que Z soluciona X, pues se supone que Z solucionaba Y y que Y soluciona X. Si no es el caso, toca:

- Revisitar y mejorar la pregunta canónica para que incluya información lo suficientemente relevante.
- Dejar abierta la pregunta X.
- Replantear si tal vez Z debería ser duplicada de Y, en lugar de al revés.

Answer (score 1):

Propongo que se resuelva este lío de la siguiente manera:

- Redactar una nueva pregunta (Charo puede hacer esto, si quiere -- pero cualquiera lo puede hacer)
- Charo que postee su respuesta completa (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32926/9385) en la nueva pregunta
- Que se canonice esa Q-A
- Que todas las demás preguntas parecidas se abran y que se cierren otra vez, enlazando a la nueva Q-A canónica

Comment: No sé si esto es más lío todavía, pero, en cualquier caso, debería ser una respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3281/).

Comment: @Charo - Pues tu no habias redactado tu respuesta todavia cuando se publico esa pregunta.

Comment: Ya, pero todavía se pueden añadir respuestas a esa pregunta, ¿no?

Comment: @Charo - Pero si mal no entendi, esa es una pregunta de Meta.  En Meta no se explican cuestiones de gramatica, solo se discute la mejor forma de organizar el material en el sitio principal.

Comment: No, me refiero a lo que tu has escrito aquí, a tu propuesta: debería ser una respuesta a la otra pregunta, la "option 3".

Comment: @Charo - ay perdon, ya no se a que te refieres.

Comment: Bueno, @aparente001, muchas gracias por tu propuesta, pero parece que finalmente se implementará la [opción 2](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3283/).