# What are multiple ways a visitor could find the canonical questions?

Tags: discusión, soporte, preguntas-canónicas, housekeeping, site-navigation

In a website, the most important information should be findable in multiple ways.  For example, an organization's phone number or email address could be in a thin banner at the top, and in the footer, and on the "Contact Us" page.

Our canonical Q-As, which we have put a lot of effort into, should be *easily findable*.  New and returning participants need to know they exist and also need to be able to find them.  So let's propose multiple places the link could be posted.

We could post these as separate posts and then moderators can weigh in about feasibility, and participants can vote to show priorities.

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

There's this **Meta post, that gets [featured](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) now and then, with a list of canonical questions**:

[¿Qué preguntas canónicas tenemos? What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/qu%C3%A9-preguntas-can%C3%B3nicas-tenemos-what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovere)

Desktop users can see it in the side panel of the Main page when it is featured. Sadly, it seems like side toolbars are not visible for mobile users.

Another way of linking to canonical questions is by **properly marking duplicates**, i.e. if a new question is a duplicate but there're several questions we could pick as target, we should always try to pick the canonical one if there's one (and improve it and mark the others as duplicates too, when needed).

Some other sites promote **using each tag's wiki to link to related canonical questions**, which would be a good idea if users actually read the tag wikis (I doubt it).

Beyond that... there's little left we can do. As a Beta site we don't get to have custom sidebars like those in [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) (we don't, do we?), which could be used for this, and I cannot think of anything else regarding "passive" promotion of canonical questions.

Of course, we can always do some **"active" promotion by linking the canonical questions in our own questions, answers and comments**.

Comment: I also doubt that much people read wiki pages

Comment: @fedorqui in fact in the wiki pages for several tags I started to add some time ago a list to the most upvoted questions for every tag, to show examples of good questions (see tags [tag:traducción], [tag:etimología], [tag:gramática] and others). I don't know if that initiative got followed by someone afterwards...